# Indirect function usage

Tags: excel, function, reference, formula, cell

I am trying to use the indirect function to refer to a cell in another workbook:

`A1` = `'C:\Users\thekv\OneDrive\Documents\accessmydocs\[KVR 4.0.xlsm]SheetOne'!$e$32`

`B1` = `indirect(a1)`

I get `#REF!`

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks for your help

I tried the above and it is not working

Comment: Is the referenced workbook open?

Comment: Generally, you don't need (and shouldn't use) `INDIRECT` to reference cells/ranges in another workbook. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f#:~:text=1%20Open%20the%20destination%20workbook%20and%20the%20source,position%20the%20cursor%20where%20you%20...%20See%20More)  for referencing external cells/ranges and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) for the function.